# Can Meteor Templates access Session variables directly?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

In my Meteor app I find myself writing a lot of things like:

```
Templates.myTemplate1.isCurrentUser = function() {
  return Session.get("isCurrentUser");
};


Templates.myTemplate2.isCurrentUser = function() {
  return Session.get("isCurrentUser");
};
```

I need many different templates (I'm using handlebars) to access the same simple value stored inside Session.

Is there a way to avoid writing the same function over and over again?
Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As meteor is currently using handlebars as default templating engine you could just define a  helper for that like:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

Template.registerHelper('isCurrentUser',function(input){
  return Session.get("isCurrentUser");
});

}
```

you can do this in a new file e.g. called helpers.js to keep the app.js file cleaner.
Once this helper is registered you can use it in any template by inserting `{{isCurrentUser}}`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, the `Handlebars.registerHelper` method is of course a good place to add globally used template elements.

Comment: I wish I saw this earlier, I'm falling back to jQuery just to add global events instead of template events

Comment: The `Handlebars` method of registering helpers was deprecated in `0.8.0`. `UI.registerHelper` is the new method of doing this.

Answer (score 46):

Building on [@cioddi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/380942/cioddi)'s answer, as you can pass parameters to the Handlebars helpers, you could make it a generic function so that you can easily retrieve any value dynamically, e.g.

```
Template.registerHelper('session',function(input){
    return Session.get(input);
});
```

You can then call it in your template like this

```
{{session "isCurrentUser"}}
```

Note that the [auth packages](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Auth) come with a global helper named CurrentUser that you can use to detect if the user is logged in:

```
{{#if currentUser}}
    ...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: @jtblin Hey in this approach, if the variable returned is an array, can you get the value in them? Like `{{session "isCurrentUser".1}}` (which doesn't work) ?

Comment: In this case you may have to create a separate method, and pass the index of the array that you want to get back in a second variable, i.e. `Handlebars.registerHelper('sessionArray',function(input, index){
    return Session.get(input)[index];
});` and call it like this `{{sessionArray "isCurrentUser" 1}}`.

Comment: [I am facing an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32806020/spacebar-meteor-nested-if-and-global-template-helpers) using this technique with nested `{{#if}}` tags

Answer (score 12):

Just a heads up to everyone: With the release of 0.8.0, `Handlebars.registerHelper` has become deprecated. Using the new Blaze engine, `UI.registerHelper` would be the new method of accomplishing this.

Updated version of @cioddi 's code

```
UI.registerHelper('isCurrentUser',function(input){
  return Session.get("isCurrentUser");
});
```

Comment: And then as of 9.x it's no longer UI.registerHelper, it's Template.registerHelper

Comment: Times they are a changin'.

Answer (score 5):

Actually now you can just use `{{#if currentUser}}`

It's a global included from the accounts/auth package..

http://docs.meteor.com/#template_currentuser

Answer (score 5):

You'll want to check out these handlebar helpers for meteor: https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers

There's a number of session helpers, one which does what you want. From the docs:

`Is my session equal to 4?: {{$.Session.equals 'mySession' 4}}`

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `isCurrentUserTemplate` and include this in your other templates with

```
{{> isCurrentUserTemplate}}
```