# pre-populating app settings witha meteor collection

Tags: collections, meteor

I'm trying to get my head around the way meteor work.
I'm building a site prototype and I'd like to pre-populate it with data like `site.title, site.logo, site.contact.number` etc...

I've created a `Settings` collection:

```
Settings = new Meteor.Collection('settings');
Settings.insert(
  {
  logo: 'test logo',
  contact: {
    human: '01 01 01 01 01',
    machine: '0101010101'
  }
}
)
```

is it possible in the html markup to then retrieve this data across templates, as Meteor is subscribed to the collection?

I'm trying to do things like:

```
    <a href="#" class="logo url" rel="me">{{settings.logo}}</a>
    <a href="{{settings.contact.machine}}" class="logo url" rel="me" {{settings.contact.human}}</a>
```

Meteor is running on auto publish at the moment so I'm not sure if I need to do something in my `main.js` file. Can Meteor access all values automatically? at the moment it prints `[object,object]`

---

## update

I've created a settings.json file:

```
{
  "public" : {
    "logo" : "my fancy company name",
    "contact" : {
      "human" : "01 01 01 01 01 ",
      "machine" : "0044101010101"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I changed my `Handlebars.registerHelper` to

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('view', function(){
  return Meteor.settings.public
});
```

I can now access all of the settings without creating a Collection for them, much more easily.

 
cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong on several levels.

The handlebar expression `{{settings.contact.machine}}` will insert `*currentContextObject*.settings.contact.machine` into the HTML, where `*currentContextObject*` is the template's data context.

What is your template's data context? I don't know but it doesn't matter because `settings.contact.machine` won't make sense either way. `Settings` is a collection of documents but you are trying to use it as if it were a single object.

What would work in JS is `Settings.findOne().contact.machine`. To access this setting across templates you would need to create a global template helper like e.g.:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Handlebars.registerHelper("getMachineContact", function() {
    return Settings.findOne().contact.machine;
  });
}
```

Then you could use `{{getMachineContact}}` in your HTML.

Still this solution wouldn't be nice and you should probably be using [Meteor.settings](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_settings) instead of a `Settings` collection for solving your use case.

Similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13060608/can-meteor-templates-access-session-variables-directly/13105238#13105238) you could then create a global template helper that returns arbitrary values from `Meteor.settings` given their path, meaning you could for example write `{{getSetting "contact.machine"}}`. This approach would involve converting a string in dot notation ("contact.machine") into an object reference so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393943/convert-javascript-string-in-dot-notation-into-an-object-reference) question might be useful.

Comment: I'm trying to do something that work a bit like a .yaml config file in jekyll. I want to set up key values to fill in the markup when I prototype. I'm looking for something basic. I actually was in my own way "almost" there. I add a helper with `return Settings.find()`. So thanks for the `Settings.findOne().blah.blah` tip :). I'm not that big on javascript so it's quite a handful of new concept here.

Comment: But just to make sure, you're saying that I don't need to  create a Settings collection as I can do the same in Meteor.settings?

Comment: Yes I can. Thanks very much for the enlightenment :)