# Meteor - handling events in nested templates... without polluting 'Session' variable

Tags: meteor

I've come across this situation several times now and I realise I'm not really confident about the 'meteor/right' way to handle it.

Suppose I have a form with several parts - each represented by a template - and within each part there are more templates representing eg. datepickers etc.

```
<template name='myForm'>
    {{>partOne}}
    {{>partTwo}}
    <button class='submit'>Submit</button>
</template>

<template name='partOne'>
    {{>widget}}
    {{>widget}}
</template>

<template name='widget'>
    <input class='datepicker' />
</template>
```

I want to keep track of my form as the user fills it out - on the level of the 'myForm' template - but all the events are happening at the level of 'widget'.

One solution I keep seeing (e.g. [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26071066/1094784)) is to just put everything in the global Session variable. Like so

```
Template.widget.events({
    'click .select' : function(event, template){
        var name = template.data.name;
        Session.set(name, $(event.currentTarget).val());
    }
});
```

And then in myForm I should do something like this

```
Template.myForm.rendered = function(){
    Tracker.autorun(function(){
        var name = Session.get('name');
        // do something
    });
}
```

But as my forms are getting more complicated, I find this is really turning into a mess on the myForm template level, all while filling up my Session variable with data that isn't really application-global.

I'd be really grateful for any ideas on how others deal with this ! Keeping templates and widgets modular while still being able to follow and react to their triggered events from parent templates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a file-level [ReactiveVar](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar) or [ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict), instead of the `Session` object.

Comment: that would work if all the widgets were in the same file... but those in other packages wouldn't have access to it

Comment: I use a global variable `G = this` on the client and server to access the global namespace, but this wouldn't get you past having several different Session variables, that don't persist. There's not a good way in Meteor that I know, yet, to share data without making it global.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it might be possible to store a ReactiveVar on the parent template's dataset, using `Template.parentData`.

Answer (score 3):

You're not alone in feeling like something just isn't right. This is one of the reasons there's a lot of talk about a Blaze 2. Here's what I do:

Create an app global namespace (e.g. `G = {}`). I usually use the first letter of the app name & do this in `lib/config/_namespace.js`

Put your collections in `G.Collections` or `G.C`,

Put your shared functions in `G.Fx`, etc...

Put your template vars in `G.T`.

Then, save that variable to `G.T.varName`. In doing so, you can use it in `rendered` as well as `events` and `helpers`. As a perk, it's super easy to find all your "globals" because they're all in the `G` object. Additionally, you can now 'use strict' again.

Then, to keep it clean:

```
Template.parentTemplate.destroyed = function() {
  G.T = {};
};
```

So if you need reactivity, just make a `ReactiveDict`:

```
Template.parentTemplate.created = function() {
  G.T.RD = new ReactiveDict();
};
```

Comment: This wasn't the approach i used to solve this particular problem, but thanks for a really useful answer all the same. There is almost no info about namespacing in the meteor literature and i've followed some of your advice